# How can I use a variable with System.Windows.Forms.Keys?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to use System.Windows.Forms.Keys with a variable for example

```
shortcutkey = "A"
keydata = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.shortcutkey
```

Is this possible?

The idea was to implement custom shortcuts that the user specifies to perform certain actions.

My code is like this

```
        If (((BindingFunctions.IsKeyDown(Keys.ControlKey) AndAlso BindingFunctions.IsKeyDown(Keys.ShiftKey)) AndAlso BindingFunctions.IsKeyDown(keyData)) AndAlso (keyData = Keys.L)) Then
            CC.LC()
        End If
```

Here I am giving keyData  = Keys.L directly. Instead of this I would like to do it with a variable like

```
        mykeydata = "L"
        If (((BindingFunctions.IsKeyDown(Keys.ControlKey) AndAlso BindingFunctions.IsKeyDown(Keys.ShiftKey)) AndAlso BindingFunctions.IsKeyDown(keyData)) AndAlso (keyData = Keys.mykeydata)) Then
            CC.LC()
        End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Dim shortcutkey As String = "A"
Dim keyData As Keys

If [Enum].TryParse(Of Keys)(shortcutkey, keyData) Then
    ' keyData is now Keys.A
End If
```

Comment: can you give the vb version. I am really new to this.

Comment: Sorry, I totally skipped over the tag. I'll update it in a little bit.

Comment: can you explain on how I can use this in the code in my question.

Comment: Your current code, where you use Keys.L, should go inside my If-block. Get rid of the `AndAlso (keyData = Keys.L)`, it doesn't need to be there: simply checking for `BindingFunctions.IsKeyDown(keyData)` should be sufficient. Basically, I've given you a way to convert a string containing "A" to an actual `Keys` that's equal to `Keys.A`.

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it worked. AndAlso (keyData = Keys.L) was used because I use keyData for multiple actions.